# Xamarin iOS Build System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "../obj/iPhone/Dev/actool/bundle/my20x20.png"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have different Info.plist files for different environments e.g. Dev.Info.plist.

NOTE: I copy and paste all contents of Dev.Info.plist into Info.plist before I start my build.

When I build & run locally, I have no issues but I build & run against iPhoneSimulator. My CI/CD pipeline runs against iPhone and for some reason, it does not pick up my image assets.

#### Error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(1057,3): error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp.iOS/obj/iPhone/Dev/actool/bundle/my20x20.png" [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp.iOS/MyApp.iOS.csproj]
```

#### iOS CSPROJ

```
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcons_Dev.appiconset\20.png">
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

#### Dev.Info.Plist

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcons_Dev.appiconset</string>
```

Comment: Could you please help confirm  that if all the app icons are copied  into Asset Catalog in your project that running in CI/CD.BTW, what CI/CD you are using?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I can confirm the image assets were being copied over. It turned out to be the bit depth of the image. I added the answer, thank you for responding to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my iOS AppIcons in the AssetCatalog had a bit depth of 24.

This comes from saving them as PNG **without** marking them as transparent. When marked as transparent they have a bit depth of 32.

After that, the build pipeline worked as intended.